# I have made an application in visual studio 2012 and went under whole process of certification but the test failed, please give me the solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

please guide me , how to change the default icon in the project in visual studio 2012 ?
due to that the certification test fails . 
Due to this error I am not able to upload it to the windows store.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but what language is this project in?  I believe you need to add the icon to the `resource` file of the project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026262/how-can-i-change-the-default-exe-icon-in-visual-studio-2012-c

Comment: What kind of application is this? Windows Store?

Comment: A Store app has *tiles*, not icons.  Project + Store + Edit App Manifest, change the Logo tiles.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default icon, first find or make an icon file.  Then do this:

1. Go to the project properties.  (Project menu.)
2. Select the Application pane.  (Probably the first one.)
3. Go to the section Resources.
4. Check the option (radio) button Icon and manifest.
5. For the Icon field, use the browse button to select your icon file.
6. Save it, build it, try the certification test again.